# two association lists scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Say I have two functions that returns association lists where one gives the total amount of bottles each person has and another that gives the amount of days it took for them to get it. How would I combine the lists by taking the average of the two lists?
Given

```
(define (lookup k alst)
  (cond [(empty? alst)
         empty]
        [(equal? k (first (first alst)))
         (second (first alst))]
        [else 
         (lookup k (rest alst))]))
```

and

```
(define (put k v alst)
  (cond [(empty? alst)
         (list (list k v))]
        [(equal? k (first (first alst)))
         (cons (list k v) (rest alst))]
        [else
         (cons (first alst) 
               (put k v (rest alst)))]))
```

So say function `(total-bottles lst)` returns
`'((bob 10) (tim 30) (sally 25))` and

`(days-taken lst)` would return
`'((bob 2) (tim 3) (sally 5))`

how would I make a function to combine the lists for an average-bottles-per-day function that would return the amount of bottles collected on average each day to return this result?
`(average lst)`
`'((bob 5) (tim 10) (sally 5))`?

Comment: Do both lists contain exactly the same persons? are the persons in exactly the same order in both lists?

Comment: yes they are in the exact order and same people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both lists contain the same people and in the same order, do as @JhonClements suggests and take a look at the recipe in HtDP. To give you an idea, here's the general structure of the solution, fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (average l1 l2)
  (if <???>                   ; if one of the lists is null
      <???>                   ; return null
      (cons (list             ; else cons a new 2-element list, its first element
             <???>            ; is the name in the current position in either list
             (/ <???> <???>)) ; and calculate the average between current elements
            (average <???> <???>)))) ; finally, advance recursion over both lists
```

Notice that for determining if one of the lists is null *and* for picking the name of the person, it doesn't matter which list you use - because we've assumed that the lists have the same length and the same people, in the same positions. For calculating the average you need to consider the current element in *each* list, though. Once you've finished, don't forget to test your solution:

```
(average (total-bottles lst)
         (days-taken lst))

=> '((bob 5) (tim 10) (sally 5))
```

Comment: How do I get the name or number out from a list of lists? I don't really understand how I would be able to it from the list. Like at the part (cons (list <...> (/ <???> <???>)) how would i be able to get the name and the number out of a list of many other lists? Would it be (cons (list (first (first l1)) (/ (second (first l1) (second (first l2)))?

Comment: @user1869703 you almost got it, there are a couple of misplaced parenthesis there, but you're on the right track. Keep trying a bit more, and you'll get it all right!

Comment: (define (average l1 l2)
  (if (or (null? l1) (null? l2))                  
      null                  
      (cons (list             
            (first (first l1))          
             (/ (second (first l1)) (second (first l2)))) 
            (average (rest l1) (rest l2))))) 

is what I ended up with and it worked with my test. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

If, as you suggest, the lists are in the same order and contain exactly the same people, then I suggest that you take a look at [section 17.2 of HtDP](http://www.htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-1.html#node_toc_node_sec_17.2), Case 2 of "Processing two lists simultaneously." It has a bunch of problems of exactly this kind.

If this is not a class-related question, then let me know.

Comment: I have read it but I'm not sure on how to apply that to list of lists. It is for class but i've been stuck here for quite a while, about two hours or so, so I decided to ask this question.